# meaning of: Eating me up inside

Tags: meaning, idioms

Example from *Ex Machina* movie:

In fact, I wanna share it with you so much, **it's eating me up inside**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figuratively, it can mean a couple of things, depending on the context (which is clear in your example).

It can mean that you are holding something in (for example, keeping something secret) and that you are keen to let it out (tell somebody). This is the context of your example.

It can also have a more negative connotation, that something is troubling you, and that you are hurting 'inside', even though you might seem ok externally.

Comment: A similar expression is to say that something is "gnawing at you."  You can look it up for more explanation, but it refers on the surface to a feeling you have in your body when your emotional state is troubled over a period of time.